# Javascript split returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if someone can help me and explain why, when I split my innerText it return `undefined` sometimes and if someone could point me in the right direction on how i can fix this

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-leaderboard-party"),
  counter = elems.length,
  arrayLength = 0,
  maxLengthArray = 0;

// LEADERBOARD NAMES
window.leaderboardNames = function() {
  var Elem;
  if (counter <= 0)
    counter = elems.length;
  Elem = elems[counter - 1];
  document.getElementsByClassName("hud-intro-name")[0].value = Elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(",")[arrayLength];
  maxLengthArray = Elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(",").length;
  if (maxLengthArray == arrayLength) {
    arrayLength = 0;
    counter--;
  } else {
    arrayLength++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hud-intro-leaderboard">
  <div class="hud-intro-leaderboard-parties">
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Player name here 1, Player name here 2, Player name here 3, Player name here 4 — <strong>998</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Player name here 5, Player name here 6, Player name here 7 — <strong>707</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Player name here 8, Player name here 9, Player name here 10 — <strong>610</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Player name here 11, Player name here 12 — <strong>448</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Player name here 13, Player name here 14, Player name here 15, Player name here 16 — <strong>409</strong></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-green" style="width: 90%;" onclick="leaderboardNames();">LEADERBOARD NAMES</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="hud-intro-name" style="width: 90%;" maxlength="29" placeholder="Your nickname">
```

Comment: You're asking for an array index that is outside the index range. Some simple debugging would show this

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays are zero-indexed and `arr[arr.length]` will **always** be undefined

Comment: console.log() is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue on your arrayLength check, needed to be +1

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-leaderboard-party"),
  counter = elems.length,
  arrayLength = 0,
  maxLengthArray = 0;

// LEADERBOARD NAMES
window.leaderboardNames = function() {
  let elem;
  
  if (counter <= 0) {
    console.log(counter);
    counter = elems.length;
    }
  elem = elems[counter - 1];
  let elemNames = elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(',');
  
  document.querySelector(".hud-intro-name").value = elemNames[arrayLength];
  
  maxLengthArray = elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(",").length;
  if (maxLengthArray == arrayLength+1) {
    arrayLength = 0;
    counter--;
  } else {
    arrayLength++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hud-intro-leaderboard">
  <div class="hud-intro-leaderboard-parties">
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">⋘TC⋙ ƘƠƦƘƲƧƲȤ, ƬƇ☢☠ⓀⓊⓇⓉ☠☢, ⋘TC⋙ ƘƠƦƘƲƧƲȤ, ƬƇ☢☠ⓀⓊⓇⓉ☠☢ — <strong>998</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Sweet Heart TW, High Score GO!, High Score GO! — <strong>707</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">K¥LË, K¥LË3, This has been removed, This has been removed — <strong>610</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Exxotic, ภคŦғเค :P... (MSR), Hauzz✔️ — <strong>448</strong></div>
    <div class="hud-leaderboard-party">Brightstar, Yaslin, Yaslin, Yaslin — <strong>409</strong></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-green" style="width: 90%;" onclick="leaderboardNames();">LEADERBOARD NAMES</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="hud-intro-name" style="width: 90%;" maxlength="29" placeholder="Your nickname">
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined would occur if the value after - doesn't have ,

So in the statement

```
Elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(",")[arrayLength];
```

You need to first check

```
Elem.innerText.split("—")[0].split(",")
```

and safely extract from that.